# Measuring Coastline of the USA (NOAA)

Tags: distance, measurements, noaa

I need to find the distance of the US coastline, I know that this is a tricky subject on account of there being several different ways to measure the coastline (and different scales). That said, for my project needs I thought that the NOAA methodology, which estimates the US total coastline to be about 95,509 miles. I downloaded a shoreline shapefile (medium resolution) from NOAA's shoreline website, created a new field in the attribute table of the layer, and measured the geometry (statue miles, Geodesic length, NAD83). When I totaled the entire Coastline of the USA from that layer it came out to over 130,000 miles, which is much higher than what was estimated. Any idea what I may be doing wrong? Could anyone point me to a shapefile download where I can validate the 95,509 estimation?

NOAA Methodology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_coastline#References

NOAA Medium Resolution Downloads: https://shoreline.noaa.gov/data/datasheets/medres.html

Comment: The NOAA methodology is hard to interpret (I haven't tried to read the 1975 pamphlet) - but I'd suggest it probably doesn't include islands, inlets, rivers etc., which the shoreline product appears to include.

Comment: I take that back, from the PDF: 'Shoreline Mileage of the outer coast includes offshore islands, sounds, bays, rivers, and creeks to the head of tidewater or to a point where tidal waters narrow to a width of 100 feet.' But, some of the rivers included are definitely not tidal, and some of the islands are so small they surely weren't part of the original 1970s data.

Answer (score 0):

They are not measuring the same area. The NOAA shoreline website says  `Coverage: Continental U.S. – does not include Alaska, the Hawaiian Islands, Puerto Rico, or other interests and territories of the U.S.` while the wiki page measures the states and `territories`.

Comment: Yes, the NOAA Shoreline does not include Alaska, Hawaii, or other territories, so in that case shouldn't it have less total length than the Wikipedia article? I am specifically just concerned with the state of California. According to NOAA methodology, it's about 3,427 miles long but when I calculate it on Pro it's closer to 8,000 miles.